# how do i remove <built-in function array> from the output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This below is a part of my program how do I remove the  from the output of this ? can it be removed?

or is it built-in? because I intend to save it as a text file after I convert it to a 2d matrix.

Also, I want to reshape the 1D array "final" as a 2D 30*5 matrix how do I do it (of course there aren't 150 elements here still, it is yet to be added by different main loop)

edited: here stmat is an array of 80 elements and t = 8 for this particular
iteration

```
t = n
t = int(t)
print(t)
import numpy
final = numpy.array
arr = ['1','2','3','5','7']
for p in arr :
    sum = 0 
    p = int(p)
    for j in range(t) :
        sum = sum + float(stmat[p])
        p = p + 10
    avg = sum/n
    final =  numpy.append (final, avg )
    print(avg)   
    print(final)
```

I get the following output

```
75.75
[<built-in function array> 75.75]
73.875
[<built-in function array> 75.75 73.875]
93.625
[<built-in function array> 75.75 73.875 93.625]
7.0
[<built-in function array> 75.75 73.875 93.625 7.0]
29.368750000000002
[<built-in function array> 75.75 73.875 93.625 7.0 29.368750000000002]
```

Comment: try `final = numpy.array()` instead of `final = numpy.array`?

Comment: You also shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name as it hides the builtin `sum` function.

Comment: final = numpy.array()
this doesn't work

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your code is not minimal, and fails on a couple of undefined symbols.

Comment: sorry the code is too long ill just edit the required details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.array` is a function, `final = numpy.array` is assigning the function itself to the variable. Calling `final()` now does the same thing as calling `numpy.array()`.

If you want to create an initial empty numpy array you should do something like `final = numpy.array([])`.

Comment: @nihalpalaksha great, if this is what you need would you like to accept the answer? Click the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

list append is better than `np.append`:

```
final = []   # empty list
arr = ['1','2','3','5','7']
for p in arr :
    sum = 0 
    p = int(p)
    for j in range(t) :
        sum = sum + float(stmat[p])
        p = p + 10
    avg = sum/n
    final.append( avg )
    print(avg)   
    print(final)
```

faster and easier to use right.